# Can cppcheck do a dry run to list all files without actually checking them?

Tags: cppcheck

I am running cppcheck on a big project and I'm trying to exclude a couple of files and folders that are 3rd party and/or generated. Is it possible to let cppcheck do a dry run and let it show the files it would normally try to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, such a functionality is not (yet) implemented.

The best solution that comes to my mind is to use options like this:

```
cppcheck --check-config ./ 2> /dev/null
```

Explanation:

- The `--check-config` option lets Cppcheck only check if includes are
  missing. No further analysis is done, no bugs are reported.
- Replace `./` with the path to the source files that you want to have the output for.
- `2> /dev/null` suppresses Cppcheck messages for missing includes and other errors

Running this on the Cppcheck sources I get an output like this:

```
$ ./cppcheck --check-config ./ 2> /dev/null
Checking addons/test/cert-test.c ...
1/291 files checked 0% done
Checking addons/test/cert-test.cpp ...
2/291 files checked 0% done
Checking addons/test/misc-test.cpp ...
3/291 files checked 0% done
Checking addons/test/misra/misra-suppressions1-test.c ...
4/291 files checked 0% done
Checking addons/test/misra/misra-suppressions2-test.c ...
5/291 files checked 0% done
Checking addons/test/misra/misra-test.c ...
6/291 files checked 0% done
Checking addons/test/misra/misra-test.cpp ...
7/291 files checked 0% done
Checking addons/test/naming_test.c ...
8/291 files checked 0% done
Checking addons/test/naming_test.cpp ...
9/291 files checked 0% done
Checking addons/test/namingng_test.c ...
10/291 files checked 0% done
Checking addons/test/path1/misra-suppressions1-test.c ...
11/291 files checked 0% done
Checking addons/test/path1/misra-suppressions2-test.c ...
...
```